# Query SQL Azure from API

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

I'm a newbie on C# and API development. Right now, I created an API with a hardcoded array to return JSON. This works and I can access it through my Xamarin mobile app.

Now I want to replace this piece by actually querying my real SQL Server database running in Azure. But I'm not able to do this... I've tried to follow [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt718320(v=sql.1).aspx) and also [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C) and come up with the below code, but for a strange reason the code gives errors on Visual Studio:

```
// this is my model
public class Word
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Spanish { get; set; }
    public string French { get; set; }
}

// below my controller
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using MyApp.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

...

SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=myServer;Database=myDb;User ID=myUserId;Password=myPswd;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;");
myConnection.Open(); // but Visual Studio gives me an error here: The name 'myConnection.Open' does not exist in the current context. The name 'myConnection' does not exist in the current context.

public IEnumerable<Word> GetAllWords()
        {
            // here I'm planning to type my query to return all words within my database
        }
```

I'm starting to wonder that this is not the approach people take, since I can't find much documentation on it... I tried to create another API from scratch and click the checkbox "Host in the cloud" but I don't want to create a new database. I just want to query an existing one...

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @SamAxe I just updated the question, this is the error : The name 'myConnection.Open' does not exist in the current context. The name 'myConnection' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: myConnection is ok so the error myst be somewhere else. Any other error messages before the "does not exist"  message?

Comment: your `myConnection.Open` line is a statement.  statements can only appear within function bodies.  They may not appear in the class definition.